# How to add initial commit and send files to existing git repo?

Tags: git

How to add initial commit and send files to existing git repo?

My try:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://user@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git
git push -u origin master

error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://user@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're operating in a pre-existing repo and pushing to an arbitrary one, check some relevant details:

```
git branch -avvv
git ls-remote origin
```

Your newly-adopted origin repo doesn't have a branch named 'master', or whatever other name your own master branch is configured to track.  If you know the name of the branch you want to tie to your master branch, you can create it with

```
git push -u origin master:user2250668
```

and unless that repo's administrator has restricted branch creation that'll do ya.